# StartAt is not working with cordova-plugin-firebasex plugin

Tags: objective-c, cordova-plugin-firebasex

I'm trying to integrate [cordova firebase plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex/blob/master/README.md#cordova-cli-builds) in to my cordova projects. I face one issue startAt is not working . If i follow the syntax mentioned in the document that is

```
['startAt', 'part_id', "1234, 'String']
```

this gives me error
after lot of debugging i found it is accepting array.

```
['startAt', ["1234], 'String']
```

this code is building with out any issues but expected results are not coming always i get first 100 results.

I have tried various debugging techniques still didn't found solution.